# Manipulate Object if it exists in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I feel like I'm making a really stupid mistake but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.

I have an instance of an object on a different layer that is keyframed to appear and disappear with an animation. I want my code to check if the object exists (at the current frame) and if it does exist, I want it to mask another object.

My code looks something like this.

```
if(this.getChildByName("mouthMask") != null){
    mouth.mask = mouthMask;
}
```

My biggest problem is that at compile time I get this error code

> "1120: access of unidentified property mouthMask"

I've tried throwing a try catch statement around everything but that doesn't seem to work either. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: and I found the answer like 5 minutes later... I just needed to refer to mouthMask in the second line as this.getChildByName("mouthMask")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned, you're still referring to `mouthMask` within your if statement.

If you use a reference to `mouthMask` throughout your code like this, you can avoid the error:

```
// Create a reference called target.
var target:DisplayObject = getChildByName("mouthMask");

if(target)
{
    mouth.mask = target;
}
```